# App Pool advanced settings using Powershell Desired Configuration State

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool, dsc

How can I modify various settings inside either a new or exisitng App Pool using Powershell?

I am interesting in some of the "Advanced" settings such as Enable 32-Bit Applications, Managed Pipeline Mode, Process Model Identity, etc. Any ideas on how I can do this? I tried using the xWebAdministration module but that seems to have very basic settings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, a custom DSC resource is the only way to do this with DSC. If you are able to use PowerShell scripting without DSC, you can use the [WebAdministration module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) module to create the pool, and then modify it from there.

```
$appPoolName = "MyAppPool"
New-WebAppPool -Name $appPoolName
$appPool = Get-Item "IIS:\AppPools\$appPoolName"
$appPool.processModel.identityType = 3
$appPool.processModel.username = "someUser"
$appPool.processModel.password = "somePassword"
$appPool.managedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0"
$appPool.managedPipeLineMode = "Integrated"
```

**Update 1/31/2015**

In the PowerShell.org community DSC modules, someone made a cWebAdministration [pull request](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/cWebAdministration/pull/4) that apparently includes "37 app pool config options". Might be a great solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only way I figured out too. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Note, at the end of the code you'll need to run [`$appPool | Set-Item`](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-making-simple-configuration-changes-to-web-sites-and-application-pools) to commit the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own custom DSC resource for doing that.

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249927.aspx) is a good starting point.

However, I recommend that you take a look at [Script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282130.aspx) resource to build the logic required for all three functions in a DSC resource and experiment before writing a resource.