# PowerShell Set-ItemProperty vs. dot to set a property

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to set a property of for example an ApplicationPool with PowerShell (version 2).
(I've a Windows 7 64 bit machine if that matters)

I see that [this example](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2013/02/24/create-iis-app-pool-and-site-with-windows-powershell.aspx) uses Set-ItemProperty and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25387981/465942) uses a dot `.` to set a property of an object / element:

```
$pool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value "v4.0"
```

versus:

```
$pool.managedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0"
```

So what's the difference? I think that the second one is much more readable, but I don't know what the implications are.

**EDIT:**
I noticed that (at least in this case) there is a difference, the `Set-ItemProperty` does save the value of the property directly, while the other method does set the value (while debugging) but does not save it afterwards. <strike>I've not found out yet why this happens. (Do you need to call something like save or commit?)</strike> See [@moonstom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400414/465942)'s answer, for Powershell 2.0  `Set-ItemProperty` is the only way or `$pool | Set-Item` for Powershell 3+ ([see sample](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-making-simple-configuration-changes-to-web-sites-and-application-pools)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working on a representation of that app pool. If you check the type of that object, you'll get a configuration element. So after setting it up, you need to push your settings back with `$pool | Set-Item`, available in PS 3.0 and above. Otherwise your only alternative is `Set-ItemProperty`

Comment: Apparently I didn't have a link to a full sample. Now I [found one](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-making-simple-configuration-changes-to-web-sites-and-application-pools), see section _SET-ITEM AND GET-ITEM_. I'm using Powershell 2.0 so will have to use `Set-ItemProperty` then.

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference. In the first one you pass the object to the Set-ItemProperty commandlet via the pipe and the commandlet setting the object property.

The second one you're setting it directly on the object. But they are functionally the same. With the second one you could also retrieve the property's value like this:

```
$value = $pool.managedRuntimeVersion
```

Comment: Thanks for your clean answer. However, I noticed that setting directly on the object does not save the value? [See sample code](https://gist.github.com/kpstolk/604120c5aaf6699d19ab). Are you sure that there's no difference or am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: That's what's happening to me too. Setting the pool via the dot notation does nothing.